# New code overwrites after git merge in branches after i executed git reset on one branch

Tags: git, git-bash

I have 2 branches, `dev/Branch_1` and `release/Branch_1`.

I worked on `dev/Branch_1` and created a release branch `release/Branch_1` for that and pushed the code to the repository but i messed up few things so had to roll back. I executed `git reset hard` on branch `dev/Branch_1` and pushed to code to repository and merged with `master` branch.

Not by mistake i started to work on release/Branch_1 and added some more functionalities and few new files to it. Now when i wanted to merge the `release/Branch_1` into `dev/Branch_1` to update the dev branch, what happens is, the code which i had written in `release/Branch_1` is removed and the new files added to `release/Branch_1` are also deleted after git merge. Nothing merges into the `dev/Branch_1`.

I tried to create a new branch, i pulled the code from `origin master` and created a new branch, `dev/Branch_2` also tried to merge the `release/Branch_1` with that, but still the new files are deleted and the new code it deleted in the new branch.

I don't know, may be it sounds crazy, but this is happening, this is the first time i am coming across such situation. 
How do i overcome this, can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You have zero code or actual commands (and output) in your question, just some vague description. Try to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you have done some commit on the wrong branch, you should not merge the *all* branch, only rebase the new commits:

```
 x--x--x--x--X--X--X release
          |
    origin/release
        dev
```

Here, `X` represent the new commits done on top of `release` (which was reset to `dev`), instead of `dev`.

A simple `rebase --onto` can fix the situation:

```
git rebase --onto dev origin/release release
git branch -f release origin/release
```

That will do:

```
origin/release
    release
      |
x--x--x
       \ 
        X'--X'--X' dev
```